# TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultPrevented' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, settimeout

I am getting this error when I do the following test:

```
it('should call pauseAnimationInterval if in focus', inject(function(SearchBoxData, intervalManager, $timeout){
  SearchBoxData.init_array = [];
  SearchBoxData.inFocus = true;
  SearchBoxData.init(intervalManager);
  console.log(intervalManager.pauseTimeout);
  console.log(intervalManager.pauseTimeoutTime);
  console.log($timeout);
  $timeout.flush(intervalManager.pauseTimeoutTime+1);
  expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('onPauseInterval', intervalManager.loopIndex);
}));
```

It breaks on `$timeout.flush(intervalManager.pauseTimeoutTime+1);`
The $timeout method is called in the `intervalManager.pauseAnimationInterval()` which is inside `SearchBoxData.init(intervalManager)`:

```
intervalManager.pauseAnimationInterval = function (){

  intervalManager.safeCancel(intervalManager.continueInterval);
  intervalManager.safeCancel(intervalManager.initInterval);
  intervalManager.initInterval = null;
  intervalManager.continueInterval = null;

  intervalManager.pauseTimeout = $timeout(function () {
    if(intervalManager.inFocus === true){
      intervalManager.loopIndex += 1;
      if(intervalManager.loopIndex >= intervalManager.maxLoopIndex){
        intervalManager.loopIndex = 0;
      }
      $rootScope.$broadcast("onPauseInterval", intervalManager.loopIndex);
      intervalManager.continueAnimationInterval();
    }else{
      // Important condition: retry after the timeout if no focus
      // main reason of glitch
      intervalManager.pauseAnimationInterval();
    }
  }, intervalManager.pauseTimeoutTime);

};
```

I was not getting this error before, I am not sure what I did wrong.

Update: Here is a stacktrace with unminified version of angularJS:

```
at /Users/foo/projects/bar/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular.js:9268:88
at Scope.$eval (/Users/foo/projects/bar/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular.js:11986:28)
at Scope.$digest (/Users/foo/projects/bar/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular.js:11812:31)
at Scope.$apply (/Users/foo/projects/bar/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular.js:12092:24)
at Object.fn (/Users/foo/projects/bar/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular.js:13627:36)
at Function.self.defer.flush (/Users/foo/projects/bar/spec/javascripts/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:126:32)
at Function.$delegate.flush (/Users/foo/projects/bar/spec/javascripts/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1689:20)
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/foo/projects/bar/spec/javascripts/unit/services/searchboxdata_service_spec.js:71:16)
```

Update 2: I traced it back to the injection of the `SearchBoxData` factory. I am not sure what is wrong with it. Simply injecting it causes the error whenever I create a $timeout instance and use the flush method.

Update 3: I noticed this happens if I inject either $location or $route in one of the dependencies (indirect ones, it happens with some basic service that I use everywhere).

Update 4: Here is a plunker to reproduce it! http://plnkr.co/edit/7XweXI?p=info

Comment: Sorry about that answer, obviously didn't pay enough attention. Will look again later ;)

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or plunker for this failing test?

Comment: @dmahapatro I managed a plunker that reproduces the error. See my edit.

Comment: The plunker did not come through. It is not saved properly I guess. Try opening the link in a separate browser. I do it always before posting any demo code in SO to make sure the plunker provided by th link has my changes. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro do you see it now? I couldnt save it so I forked it.

Comment: Glad you got the answer. I was late. Was about to mention the problem with `spyOn`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Scope events which are $broadcast()'d or $emit()'d are synchronous, and return the event object when they're finished.

Some things in Angular depend on the returned event object, such as ngRoute.

So what you can do to fix this is simply add `andCallThrough()` when you create your spy, so that it calls the original function and yields a return value.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the real $broadcast, you can use `andCallFake()` to supply a fake function which can return anything you want.

Example:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  module('MyApp');
  inject(function($injector){
    rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    spyOn(rootScope,'$broadcast').andCallThrough(); // will prevent the reference error
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @chronicsalsa, That problem haunted me for days.

Comment: Good catch. I would not have got that without the plunker in question. :) As we know, a problem well stated is half solved. ;)

Comment: Note that in Jasmine 2.0 and up, the syntax is `and.callThrough();`

Comment: Please update your answer to use Jasmine 2.0 syntax.