# Testing $broadcast event

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a problem with angular tests. I'm trying to test that $broadcast was successfully fired. I'm having some strange behavior trying to use spyOn. If you have any suggestions please help I've been trying to solve this for hours. My test looks like this:

```
describe('Signup controller', function() {

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  describe('SignupCtrl', function(){
    var $scope, ctrl, $httpBackend, AUTH_EVENTS, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $controller,
      _$httpBackend_, _apiUrl_, _AUTH_EVENTS_){

        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('SignupCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        apiUrl = _apiUrl_;
        AUTH_EVENTS = _AUTH_EVENTS_;
        spyOn($rootScope, "$broadcast");
      }
    ));

    afterEach(function() {
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should show error message from API', function() {
      var apiMessage = 'That email already exists.';
      $httpBackend.expectPOST('/users').respond(400, {
        message: apiMessage
      });

      // call controller register function with mock empty credentials
      $scope.register({});

      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith(AUTH_EVENTS.signupFailed);
      expect($scope.errorMessage).toBe(apiMessage);
      expect($scope.showErrorMessage).toBe(true);
    });

  });
});
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(), oldUrl).
            defaultPrevented')
  at /src/web/src/vendor-bower/angular/angular.js:9789
  at /src/web/src/vendor-bower/angular/angular.js:12595
  at /src/web/src/vendor-bower/angular/angular.js:12407
  at /src/web/src/vendor-bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1438
```

Comment: I think this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721657/typeerror-cannot-read-property-defaultprevented-of-undefined

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `spyOn(rootScope,'$broadcast').andCallThrough();` and let me know how it goes. Also see my comment.

Comment: It actually worked. Thanks Alex this was bugging me for some time. Just one note in jamsine 2.0 its and.callThrough();

Comment: Thanks, I got very annoyed by these issue. It suddenly appeared after migration to ui-router.